# Psi4 gradient calculation with complete basis set?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I'm trying to set up a gradient calculation for psi4. In my input.dat file, I have tried the following keywords:

```
set basis cc-pVTZ
gradient('CCSD(T)')
```

which is not working. Does anyone have any recommendations on what key words to use at the end of my input file to run a gradient calculation with a CBS? Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: What do you mean "with a complete basis set"?

Comment: Can you give the entire input file and the error? It could be dying because you never tell it to do an RHF calculation. I can't remember if Psi4 has a problem with that or if it will just assume that's what you want for a reference. Also, the syntax for a direct call to the gradient is here: http://www.psicode.org/psi4manual/1.0.0/opt.html

You might need to type something like:
G, wfn = gradient('ccsd(t)', return_wfn=True)
wfn.gradient().print_out()
np.array(G)

This just mimics the manual example in which you take back the wavefunction object and print the associated gradient.

Comment: A triple zeta basis is far from complete, especially for coupled cluster methods. The entire input file would be necessary to reproduce your specific issue, and recommend further steps.